# How do I add Emoji smileys?

Tags: 7, comments

I want to add Emoji smiles in Drupal 7 comments without using a sandbox project like https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mparker17/2078481.

Does anyone have any idea how to add Emoji smiles in comments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to **[Drupal 7.50 released](https://www.drupal.org/blog/drupal-7-50)**, Emojis were added as a new feature in 7.50

> Support for full UTF-8 (emojis, Asian symbols, mathematical symbols)
>   is now possible on MySQL
>
> If content creators on your site have been clamoring to use emojis,
>   it's now possible on Drupal sites running MySQL (it was previously
>   possible on PostgreSQL and SQLite). Turning this capability on
>   requires the database to meet certain requirements, plus editing the
>   site's settings.php file and potentially other steps, as described in
>   the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2761183).
>
> [image]

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at [Smiley](https://www.drupal.org/project/smiley)

> Smiley is a text filter that substitutes text emoticons, like
>   :-) with images.
>
> It comes with a set of example smileys, but you can import
>   ready-to-use packages (e.g.: from phpBB's "pak"s and Adium Emoticon
>   packs) or define your own.
>
> To use your own smileys, simply upload them into
>   FILES_DIRECTORY/smiley (usually sites/default/files/smiley) and import
>   them using the "Smiley Import" module.

Since it is a text filter, you should be enable to for `filtered-html` and have it apply to comments.

Answer (score 4):

Emoji's are also commonly referred to as Smileys. Take a look at the [Smiley module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smiley) for Drupal 7.